# can you train tensorflow-model-garden model in Colab?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-model-garden

I'm trying to train a text detector model using [this project (unified detector)](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/projects/unified_detector) on Google Colab's gpu , this project requires `tf-nightly` but apparently upgrading Colab's tensorflow to > 2.8 breaks the gpu support , so is there a solution or it's currently impossible